# Windows XP log off script not running

Tags: windows-xp, logoff

I've written two .cmd scripts - "logon.cmd" and logoff.cmd"

I've set the "logon.cmd" to run using the gpedit.msc.
Similarly I've done so with the logoff.cmd.

My logon script runs fine but my logoff script does not run at all.

I've dummed down my logoff.cmd to the following line to test it.

```
echo testing testing > test.log
```

Still not running.

Please advise.

[image: logon]
[image: logoff]

Answer (score 0):

There may be other issues involved, but for the first step, try it using a UNC path for the logfile. 
example:

echo testing testing >\\myserver\myshare\mylogfolder\test.log

Without using UNC path, windows has to guess where the file should go. when you do

C:

cd mywork\sub-folder

this sets the default location for windows to use if you do not tell it where the file goes. With a unc path, windows has the exact path to the file and does not use defaults.